# Java How to make a package launcher, to open packages in a project

Tags: java, swing, package

I am wondering what is the best way to do this? I have two packages in a Java project: game, and maker. The game is my 2d platformer, and the maker will be the map maker. The only way to switch between the two right now is manually through the run configurations. How can I make it so when the program is run, I can choose to open the game or the map maker?

Comment: So you have 2 classes with `main()` methods?

Comment: Yes, both have main classes. My question should be, how to launch the main in each package from code, as how I ask the user is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a launcher class with a `main()` method, and use that as the main entry point.
Have the `main()` method of the launcher class allow the user to select whether they want to play or make maps, then simply call the relevant `main()` method from the other class:

```
public class Launcher {
  ...
  public void main(String[] args) {
    ... decide which action is wanted ...
    if (playGame) { Game.main(gameArgs); }
    else if (makeMaps) { MapMaker.main(mapMakerArgs); }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create two different `main` methods in two different classes, run the `main` you want to run.

Alternatively you could do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Yes to open game, no to open map maker", "Starting Up", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        //start up the game
    } else {
        //start up the map maker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pop a `JDialog` asking *"Map or Play?"*.

I don't know what you mean by *"the run configurations"* but it sounds like you are talking about an IDE.  How it is run in an IDE is irrelevant to an end user, who will almost certainly not be able to manually change run-time configurations.